# hex value is treated as decimal value

Tags: 8051

[image]

This is from Mazidi's book on microcontroller. As we can see we are aiming to add these two values 17H and 28H in HEX and want to get their sum in BCD, definitely their sum is 3F and which should be
0110 0011, then how the book says "the result should have been 0100 0101? moreover 17+28=45, as if we are taking these as decimal value, rather it should be 17H+28H=3FH=0110 0011 in BCD.This is what we want. then why all these ?

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is – whether I write 23 or 17H makes no difference, as it's the same number. 3FH is **not** 01100011_b, but 00111111_b, so I'm not sure where all these calculations come from.

Comment: @MarcusMüller  WE want the result in BCD , not in binary. this why 0110 0011, it is in BCD not in binary.

Comment: Ah, so the book is not phrasing this very well: you add 6H to 3F, to get the correct upper digit.

Comment: @Sayan the 17H and 28H is a pair of two digit BCD numbers ... they do NOT represent decimal 23 and 40

Comment: By the way: In all honesty, I know this is probably relevant to you for exam reasons, but since the 1970s, BCD is really something you don't care about. You just write a decimal-to-BCD converter in a programming language, and your compiler implements that correctly; it's never something you need to do at any rate that is high enough to even care for efficiency. As for demonstrating binary algorithms, I find it's a terrible example. So, if there's something hard to understand in your book, don't hesitate to consult other literature, too; you'll never encounter BCD problems outside uni.

Comment: @MarcusMüller actually I am not a technical student, I am learning all these for my own, I dont want to skip the section this is why asked the question, yes it is true that later on there is hardly any topic which requires understanding BCD.

Comment: @Sayan that's pretty cool! Yeah, then don't overestimate the importance of BCD; user253751's answer is pretty good. In reality, you'd never calculate in BCD, but only convert to a decimal representation at the very, very end, when you need to convert things to a human readable form – and that's not going to be BCD.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's what BCD is: basically treating hex as decimal. You take the number, write it in decimal, then stick H on the end and read it as hex.

So the decimal number 45 (hex 2D) in BCD is 45H (decimal 69) and the decimal number 17 (hex 11) in BCD is 17H (decimal 23).

You can also think of it as a way of storing decimal digits. We store each decimal digit **separately** in binary. We don't convert the whole number to binary, only each digit. So 1234 -> 1 2 3 4 -> 0001 0010 0011 0100, **not** 0000 0100 1001 0010 which is how that number would be stored in binary.

If you want to do math on numbers in this format, you have to do decimal math. Computers can only do binary math, so we have to simulate it. Because each digit is binary, binary math works just fine on the individual digits. But as soon as one digit carries over into the next, we have a problem, because binary math will let the digits go up to 15 before carrying. We can fix that by adding 6 to any digit which goes higher than 9. 6 is how much you have to add to turn 10 (decimal) into 10H (hex).  This basically converts any decimal carry into a hex carry.

For example if you get 11 (decimal) in a digit, you can add 6 to turn it into 17 (decimal) which is 11H (hex) which is what you want it to be so it carries into the next hex digit.

Comment: it really helped me a lot, thank you.

Comment: Bit of ambiguity: don't know if your 'interpret' refers to the user or the computer. For the user, it's interpreted as decimal but encoded as hex. Otherwise a good answer and upvoted.